# How to create unit tests with Windows 8 metro applications that queries Twitter API (by linqtotwitter nuGet)

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, twitter, windows-8

I'm developping an application in Windows 8 that query the Twitter API by linqtotwitter nuGet.
So, I have some functions like `getFollowers()`, `getFollowing()`, `getScreenName()` `getUserInformation()`.
All of my functions are querying Twitter and I don't know how to create unit tests with these kind of functions.

Can someone give me an example?

There is for example my getFollowers() function :

```
 public List<string> RecupererFollower()
    {
        _log.Info("Fonction récupérer follower");
        _log.Info("On recherche les follower de "+MainPage.texte);
        _log.Info("Cette fonction va créer une liste des id des follower de"+MainPage.texte);

        List<string> idFollowers=new List<string>();
        var followers =
            (from follower in MainPage.twitterCtxProp.SocialGraph
             where follower.Type == SocialGraphType.Followers &&
                   follower.ScreenName == MainPage.texte 
             select follower)
             .ToList();
        idFollowers = followers[0].IDs;

        return idFollowers;

    }
```

How can I create a test with it?
What are mockObjects?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would see if the Twitter API you are using implements an interface (it probably does). If so, then you should be able to mock out that connection and test that your code does what you intend, and then that it CALLS the API method with the expected parameters.

[Mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) are essentially a way to disconnect the code under test from more complicated or slow-running code, or code that connects to another system, like the database or, in this case, twitter.

If you are new to mocking frameworks, look at the documentation for either of these suggested frameworks: [RhinoMocks](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks) or [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/). Personally, I prefer Rhino and find it has better documentation. But there are LOTs of options.

For the above example, You would "mock" the call to the twitter API with something like the following, and then your code would consume the results you provided as though it had called twitter.

```
mockTwitterAPI.Setup(x => x.SocialGraph).Returns(MyCustomDataForThisTest());
```

Comment: I can't install these nuGet because of the incompatibility with .net 4.5 Framework...

Comment: You can just download either of them and reference the binaries directly. In both cases it's just a single reference. Although I'm not sure why nuget wouldn't let you install them -- I use them in 4.5 projects.